# I want where the "ReceiptDate=? should be the current system date.... and I want to write how to get the current system date in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
SELECT        
    SUM(ReceiptDetails.ItemSellPrice * ReceiptDetails.ItemQty) AS TotalSalesForToday
FROM            
    (ReceiptDetails 
INNER JOIN
    Receipt ON ReceiptDetails.ReceiptID = Receipt.ReceiptID)
WHERE
    (Receipt.ReceiptDate =?)
```

Comment: Use `GETDATE()` in SQL to get current system date & time.

Comment: Hello Francis, which Database is this for ?

Comment: @Marged this is for access database

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the Getdate does not work

Comment: `GETDATE()` is for SQL Server. For Access DB try `DATE()` or `NOW()` function.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks the now() works but what i tried to achieve didn't go through

Comment: In future, please ask a question in your question. A question containing nothing but some SQL code is not a question.  The title should be a very brief summary of the problem in general and then the question should be a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the entire problem, including ALL relevant details.  Also, please apply all tags that are relevant and none that are not.  You used the VB.NET tag when the question has nothing to do with VB.NET and didn't include the Access tag.

Comment: *"what i tried to achieve didn't go through"*.  That means nothing to us.  Use your words.  Provide an actual explanation of what ACTUALLY happened.  Assume that we have no idea what you're doing... because we have no idea what you're doing.  We only know what you tell us so tell us EVERYTHING that is relevant.

Comment: @FrancisMonyo You need to explain in detail what things and/or desired results you want to achieve with current query. Putting SQL query without further explanation will confusing readers about what objectives you have.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the sql code above is what i want to use to generate a report which sum up Today Sales in the reciept and recieptdetails table in my POS project

Comment: Use Date() not Now() . Now includes the current time as well, which will almost certainly not match any of your data. Date() returns the date at 00:00 which is probably what you  have stored as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DATE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-dd7a1f27-d957-4969-ab35-01e0bfbfed76) function.

If the value is indeed a date, then a direct comparison will work:

```
WHERE Receipt.ReceiptDate = DATE()
```

If `ReceiptDate` also has a time component, then:

```
WHERE Receipt.ReceiptDate >= DATE() AND
      Receipt.ReceiptDate < DATEADD("day, 1, DATE())
```